# Creating XML in iPhone SDk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, sdk

Can we create an XML document in iPhone SDK as we can in Mac OS SDK using NSXMLElement?
Is there any API or class which can help?

Answer (score -1):

this might help you:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project